# Save all windows as session to resume later

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

When I do `Project` > `Save Project As...` ST writes a project and workspace file, but only for the active window. Attempting to restore from that project file will only restore that one window. How can I save a project with all windows?

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text 3 has workspaces. I believe 2 does as well, just click and drag your file onto the window and it should pop up. 
So make a file you want to be your 'workspace' and click and drag it onto sublime text. When you done just save your work and exit. When you want to reopen it just drag that file onto the sublime text editor and it should all appear.
^ Is what i personally do and it works well.

Here is a link to sublime text 3 though in case you're interested. http://www.sublimetext.com/3

Comment: When I save my project, it creates a project and workspace file. But dragdropping that workspace only restores one window. The window that was active when I saved.